# How to convert string to int in numba

Tags: numba

I am trying to convert string to int in the numba jit function by using `int()` function, but result with error `int([unichr x 18])`

is this function not supported? or is there any another way to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: string functions are not yet supported by Numba. You can write your own function to do the conversion but this is rather bug-prone and tedious.

Comment: Numba issue: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5650